# Compile Error - gcc not respecting case sensitive file naming schemes ‍♂️

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I have a class called `Queue` inside a file called `Queue.h`. It can be found at the path `repo/API/rtos/Inc/Queue.h`. This class is designed to be a wrapper around the FreeRTOS C Library.

`Queue.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "cmsis_os.h"

template<class T, uint32_t queue_size>
class Queue
{
public:
  Queue(){};
  // etc.
```

The FreeRTOS C Library lives in the path `repo/middleware/FreeRTOS` and has a file named `queue.h` which can be found at the path `repo/middleware/FreeRTOS/Source/queue.c`.

I assumed the compiler would be able to differentiate between `Queue.h` and `queue.h`, but instead it is giving me a fairly strange error.

```
In file included from middleware/FreeRTOS/Source/queue.c:38:
API/rtos/Inc/queue.h:21:9: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token
   21 | template<class T, uint32_t queue_size>
      |         ^
make: *** [build/queue.o] Error 1
```

If you look closely at the error, you can see that the compiler is trying to compile `API/rtos/Inc/queue.h` (note the lower-case `q`) - but this file simply does not exist. In fact, it never existed. And even if it did exist, why is the compiler taking all the code from `Queue.h` and putting it in this imaginary `queue.h`?

What is going on!

Comment: What OS is your compiler running in?  Windows and MacOS have caseless filesystems.

Comment: And the file obviously exists, why do you even bother to claim otherwise?

Comment: @Blindy I can't see it anywhere in my file system ‍♂️. I would blame the elusive and mysterious "cache", but I never even made a file named `queue.h` before.

Comment: @SteveSummit I am running MacOS. Using the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and `arm-none-eabi-g++` compilers

Comment: @scottc11 I can't explain exactly why you're seeing those results, but I can say that when I set up an arm compiler on my Mac (so that I could do some Raspberry Pi kernel development), I had to create a nonstandard, caseful Mac filesystem to do it in, because the caselessness of the default MacOS filesystem was killing me.